# Mimicing the tab key being pressed in Silverlight TextBox KeyDown event

Tags: silverlight, textbox, keydown

Title pretty much explains it all really. I need to know how to automatically jump to the next element (the element that would get focus if the user presses the "Tab" key), whatever that may be, in the KeyDown event of a Silverlight TextBox. My TextBoxes are generated dynamically so I can't, for example, manually code TextBox1 to set focus on TextBox2 on keydown etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe there is an easy way to accomplish this. The only method I know of is to use the [VisualTreeHelper and get all the elements and then loop through them by their tab stop values](http://forums.silverlight.net/p/23746/85192.aspx).

If your textboxes are generated dynamically you could use a Behavior to set their tab stop properties pretty easily which would be a much better solution. Or just set it when you create them.